# Move preloader out of main.js backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, program-entry-point, preloader

I am making an backbone single page and after the site has grown so has the main js file. now its so big that i would be nice to move the loader out of the main.js file. Is there a best practice on how to load some backbone (the loader) then load the main js file?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code?  It isn't clear what you mean by the "preloader" and "the loader"....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're making some API/AJAX call(s) when your app boots up for the first time. If your initial load includes making the user wait until this initial payload is received by your client-side app, then it is probably best to show them 'something' in the meantime.

Hopefully your loader is not a major portion of your main.js. Loaders are usually pretty low level, simplistic views; if they are even views at all. I've seen some pretty clever solutions that use CSS only for loading states where all you do is add a 'loading' class to an area of the DOM when a request for data is made. The rules you write could show the words 'loading...' along with spinner if that's the intent... (here's some scss)

```
.loading.some-div {
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Loading...';
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

I don't advise loading the 'pre-loader' and then the 'main.js'. You might try 'showing' the loader when you make ajax calls to the back-end for data. Tie the loading of your application to the ACTUAL loading of data, etc.

I've also seen solutions that render a backbone view in a 'loading state', and then after the view receives data, it will hide/remove the loading state and display a fully rendered template.

```
render: function (data) {

  // the el is displaying 'loading...' until valid data is 
  // passed to the view

  if (!data) { return; }

  // when valid data is received, then the loading state is removed
  this.$el.html(this.template(data));
}
```

This is a super basic idea, but hopefully something to get your wheels spinning again. Let me know if you want to talk it out.